# download manager failed to download a file on lg g devices

Tags: android, android-download-manager, nexus-5, lg

When i'm trying to run the following code on my nexus 5 it shows a progress bar and actually download the file.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setDescription("");
                    request.setTitle("");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    }


                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
                    manager.enqueue(request);
                }
```

but when i try the same thing on a lg g2 or lg g3 the file doesn't even start download and i get this message right after the beginning. 
[image: on lg devides]

I think the problem is that lg phones have a different music dir and `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC` gives me an empty dir. If that is the problem does anyone know a way to get a correct dir for **all** devices? and if not does anyone have a clue what is the problem and how do i get it fixed?

Comment: I have the same issue. But this notification can appear at the random moment of time after download was started

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a bad name into the `getSystemService()` call:

```
(DownloadManager) getSystemService( Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC );
```

Should be something like:

```
(DownloadManager) getSystemService( DOWNLOAD_SERVICE );
```